# How to find multiplicative orders of all elements in $Z_{p^{2}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

I am working on some finite fields over $Z_{p^{2}}$ and I want to compute multiplicative orders of all elements in this field. Off the top of my head, I'd say I should multiply each $p^{2}-1$ element with itself and compute modulus ${p^{2}}$ continuously till I get "1" as result. The order of that element is the number of multiplications. Is that a correct approach or not?

**EDIT 1 -** Suppose I want to compute multiplicative orders of all elements in $Z_{3^{2}}$:

$1 \rightarrow 1 $

$2 \rightarrow 1, 2, 4, 8, 7, 5, 1$

$3 \rightarrow 1, 3, 0$

$4 \rightarrow 1, 4, 7, 1$

$5 \rightarrow 1, 5, 7, 8, 4, 2, 1$

$6 \rightarrow 1, 6, 0$

$7 \rightarrow 1, 7, 4, 1$

$8 \rightarrow 1, 8, 1$

So, none of the elements in this field has the order equal to $p^2-1=8$. Does it mean that this field doesn't have any primitives or I am missing something?

Comment: What is $Z_{p^2}$ here? The field with $p^2$ elements is not the same thing as $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @carmichael561 $p$ is a prime, for example $p=13$ and I want to compute multiplicative orders of elements over $Z_{13^{2}}$

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What is the definition of $Z_{p^2}$?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it's all the elements in $GF(p^2)$. @carmichael561

Comment: Well in that case $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}^{\times}$ is cyclic of order $p^2-1$, but I know of no general way of finding a generator besides trial and error.

Comment: Your calculations showed you that $R=\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}$ is not a field. This is because $3$ and $6$ turned out to be nilpotent (a power became zero), and therefore you never get back to $1$ as a power, and those elements don't have an inverse in $R$. You can construct the field of nine elements as $GF(9)=\Bbb{Z}_2(i)$ with $i^2=-1$, when the elements are of the form $a+bi$, $a,b\in\Bbb{Z}_3$. Caveat: that same recipe does not give you all the fields $GF(p^2)$. If $p\equiv1\pmod4$, then there is a square root of $-1$ already in $GF(p)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notation, the question you're asking makes sense if you are referring to the multiplicative group of invertible elements, namely $G=(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2})^*$. Then it is know since Gauss that a group of this kind is cyclic and it has order $|G|=\varphi(p^2)=p(p-1)$. In your example, the order is 6 and, in fact, you have generators (2 and 5).